# Is there a Zend_Form_Element that renders a plain div with some content?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Working on a bunch of forms at the moment and I'm finding that I want to be able to split a form into sections with some text in between. Is there a Zend_Form_Element that simply allows me to place some text mixed in with my form (not as a label or description linked to an individual input)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's not.

Although, you can do one of the following things:

- If the text inbetween is more like a title, you can group them in [display groups](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.displaygroups).
- If you want to put a lot of text then you'll have to write your own [custom form element](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.custom).

If you choose the second option beware of your form decorations. If you want the text to be from side to side of the page (ie. without the labels space to the left and not aligned to the rest of the input forms) you'll probably have to [disable default decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.decorators) and set new ones.